# Magento 2 set created time and updated time in database

Tags: magento2, database, date

I am using php function now() to set current date and time.But getting an error.

So please help me how can I set current date time in magento 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`protected $_dateFactory;`

```
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory $dateFactory
    ) {        
        $this->_dateFactory = $dateFactory;       
    }
```

then write this to get current date

`$date = $this->_dateFactory->create()->gmtDate();`

Answer (score 2):

For getting current date time ,you should use [dateDateTime Factory](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/DateTime/DateTime.php#L14) class's function [date()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/DateTime/DateTime.php#L90).

use `$this->_dateFactory->create()->date()` for set current date.

First,you need to **inject**  `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory` at your `__construct()` function.Then by *calling date() function ,you will get current date.* **This function ability to Converts input date into date with timezone offset**

```
 public function __construct(
...
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory $dateFactory,
.....
    ) {
    ...
         $this->_dateFactory = $dateFactory;
    ....       
        parent::__construct(
        ...
        );
    }
```